# getting "expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" when working with constants

Tags: php, constants

i have the following piece of code in php:

```
define('QUERY', $some_query_string);
if(empty(QUERY) || mb_strlen(QUERY) < 4):
    //worn the user about incorrect query input
endif;
```

when running this script i'm getting the fallowing error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`, but when i'm using an ordinary variable instead of constant everything works just fine!

The usage of constant is not required, but i would appreciate if anyone could explain why i'm getting that error?

(i'm newby here, so please tell me if i have to provide more details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty` only works with *variables*. If you want to check whether a constant has been defined, use [`defined`](http://php.net/defined). The error messages invalid uses of `empty` produce aren't necessarily very intuitive, the message about T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM mostly means the parser tripped up.

Comment: in this case the constant will be defined anyway, so i only need to check if it has contents. Anyway, i've tried ma `if` statement without `empty()` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: This is not the parser tripping up. Since empty expects a variable, and QUERY does not start with `$`, the parser expects a static class variable and therefore something like this: `QUERY::...`. PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM is the name for `::`

Comment: so here is the answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: @mensi So you're saying it's basically... a parsing problem? :)

Comment: @deceze, I guess it's nitpicking but I think there is a subtle difference between the parser tripping up and the parser correctly complaining about an unexpected token if another one would be appropriate. The name "PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" is a joke however ;)

Comment: @mensi Well, "parser tripping up" as in "when a bare word is used inside `empty()`, it's expected to be a class name followed by paamayim followed by a variable name; the parser did not expect to find a constant there". To me that classifies as "parser tripping up", which is the reason for the error message. Anyway, back to more productive discussions... :)